# How to use android cards and scrollview to build layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to develop android app with material effects like card view. This is an application that use material design. I need the same, but cannot implement this one.

[image]

Comment: I'm not really know, but it's looks like `custom AlertDialog` with `listview`...

Comment: Nope friend, that's not. This is with cardview with v7-appcompact lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please visit below link:

http://hmkcode.com/material-design-app-android-design-support-library-appcompat/

You need `android-support-v7-appcompat`, `cardview` and `design` library for it.

Comment: Thank you @Sagar, this is what i looking for.